# access to $pdo in function

Tags: php, function, pdo

I'd like to select different data from my database using a function. Unfortunately I don't have access to `$pdo` in the function. Here is the code for better understanding:

config.php

```
...
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user, $password);
```

select.php

```
include 'config.php';

function abc($sql) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
}

$sql = "SELECT a FROM table WHERE b = :name";
abc($sql);

$sql = "SELECT a FROM table WHERE c = :name";
abc($sql);
```

Error:

> Call to a member function prepare() on null

If I put the config.php into the function, it works like a charm.

Comment: Here is canonical: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/1839439 @billKarwin Could you add it in, please?

Comment: I have reopened this question, but I can't re-vote to close now. Please vote this question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/1839439

Answer (score 0):

You may declare `$pdo` as global, or pass it as a second parameter to `abc`. What's the problem with that ?

Comment: certainly not, a PHP var is not global and can't be accessed withing a function, unless "imported" inside with the `global` keyword. Please refer to PHP doc.

Comment: But I should have access to $pdo using $GLOBALS['pdo']?

Comment: Or even better, how can I pass $pdo to the funcion too? Using abc($sql, $pdo) din't work.

Comment: if it doesn't work, you `$pdo` var is not initialized correctly I guess.

Comment: It worked, I have no idea what I've done before ;). Passing $pdo to the function should be a good solution, right?